# Angular Error: Cannot match any routes error redirect to 404

Tags: angular, typescript

I have so many url, and sometimes I can not handle all error with

**core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'**

Does someone knows some common solution to handle this kind of error, and redirect user to 404, somekind of interceptor or something else, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the wild card in route, If path does not match then it will redirect to error component which will be common for handling error page.

eg.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
];
```

Here,

If a non existent page is called, then the first two route gets failed. But, the final wildcard route will succeed and the PageNotFoundComponent gets called.